# Database schema - booking platform

Tags: database, postgresql, dataframe, database-design

I am a CS student working on a small personal project. It's a platform where a user can book an appointment with a freelance photographer. I am going to use Postgres for this project and I still have few issues when I am designing my database.

```
 Photographer:
        photographer_id (PK)
        name (string)
        registration_date (string)
        company_id (int) # as photographers are not full time employee, they do have their own company 
        id_path (string) # id picture path (passport for example) 
        rating (int)
        
    
    User:
        user_id (PK)
        name (string)
        registration_date (string)
    
    
    Shooting:
        shooting_id (PK)
        photographer_id (FK) 
        user_id (FK)
        date (date)
        pictures_path (string) #path where the pictures of the shooting are stored
        location_id (FK)
        

    Location:
        location_id (PK)
        country (String)
        city (String)
```

A user is requesting a shooting for a given `day`, `time` and `location`. A shooting is always 30 minutes. Once a user is making an appointment, the platform have the kind a photographer available at the given day, time and location. Example: `user_z` is requesting a shooting at `Berlin` on `November 23th` at `3:00 pm`. The platform will look for all photographers available at that given time and location. Let' say that on `November 23th` at `3:00 pm` in `Berlin` we have 3 photographers available:

```
photographer_id | name
------------------------
3746            | Thomas
5436            | Sofia
0835            | Maria
```

We are not going to reach out the 3 of them and the faster to reply will get the job. Instead, each photographer will have a score based on 2 criteria: 1) `rating` and 2) `cancellation rate`

*the cancellation rate is the number of appointments a photographer cancel after accepting the job.*

So photographers are going to be ranked based on that score. If we come back to the example for `Berlin` on `November 23th` at `3:00 pm` the queue looks like this:

```
photographer_id | name   | score
--------------------------------
3746            | Thomas | 0.32 
5436            | Sofia  | 0.48
0835            | Maria  | 0.95
```

The platform will send a request to Maria first. If she does not reply after 30 minutes or she decline, we will send a request to Sofia and so on. I create a new table for that but I am still not very sure about the structure and I still have a lot of things to figure out.

```
    Requests:
        request_id (PK)
        user_id (FK) #from the user table
        date_of_request (date) #when the request was made by the user on the platform
        location_id (FK) # from the location table, where the client wants to have a shooting
        date (date) # when the client wants to have a shooting
        cancelled (boolean) # true is the request was cancelled by the client or no photographer was found for the given location and time
```

I don't know if what I doing make sense at all but I have some difficulties with the request table. -

- Should I had another column, `photographer_id (fk)` from the `photographer` table or `shooting_id (fk)` from the `shooting` table ? Because if a photographer accept a request, I need to be able to link it? My issue is the `requests` and `shooting` table have a lot of duplicate columns.
- My second issue is with the score to rank photographers. I need two elements to calculate that score
  `rating` and `cancellation rate`. I already have the rating in the `photographer` table but I don't have yet the `cancellation rate` score. I am still figuring out how I will be able to calculate that score on the platform (Flask) but I guess I will need a dedicated table for that score?

If you have some others suggestions, it would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have is pretty good. But I have indicated some suggestions for you to consider.

```
Photographer:
     photographer_id (PK)
     name (string)
     registration_date (string)
     company_id (int) # as photographers are not full time employee, they do have their own company 
     id_path (string) # id picture path (passport for example) 
     rating (int)
  
  Changes       
  protogrepher_id   int generated  identity
  registration_date should be type date not string
  add: contact information, unless that is in company       
     
Client:
     client_id (PK)
     name (string)
     registration_date (string)
  
  Changes
  make name client (indicates the purpose of entity, further within IT user often has bad connotation)      
  client_id           int generated  identity
  registration_date should be type date not string 
  add contact information (see Requests)   
 
Location:
     location_id (PK)
     country (String)
     city (String) 
  
  change        
  protogrepher_id   int generated  identity
  registration_date should be type date not string
  add: address (what happens if there are multiple locations in same city
               say from your example Berlin- a city of 4M inhabitants covering 30K sq km)       
 
 Requests:
    request_id (PK)
    client_id (FK) #from the client table
    date_of_request (date) #when the request was made by the client on the platform
    location_id (FK) # from the location table, where the client wants to have a shooting
    date (date) # when the client wants to have a shooting
    cancelled (boolean) # true is the request was cancelled by the client or no photographer was found for the given location and time
  
  change        
  protographer_id   int generated  identity
  registration_date should be type date not string  
  date  should be timestamp as that included the time as well as date      
  add: status  Pending  - Request made, but no photographer 
              Accepted - Photographer has accepted job
              Canceled - The request is canceled, can indicate why/who canceled 
  add: contact information (see Client)  - need to be able to notify client when accepted or canceled. That information could come from client table          
              
Shooting:
    shooting_id (PK)
    photographer_id (FK) 
    client_id (FK)
    location_id (FK)        
    date (date)
    pictures_path (string) #path where the pictures of the shooting are stored

  change        
  shooting_id   int generated  identity
  registration_date should be type date not string      

This is the decision do you need to make:  keep this as an individual table, or combined into Requests. Either way a session is an Approved Request. As you indicated the columns overlap considerable - but that is not necessary. You can combine them bu moving photographer_id to Requests and eliminating Shootings or keep Shootings but eliminate Client_id, location_id, and date then adding Request_Id. There is no loss of information either way.
```

**Your specific questions:**

- Add Shooting_id to Photographer. **Absolutely Not**. What happens if
  the photographer has multiple shootings? You can get the needed
  information through the FK from Shooting to Photographer.
- I cannot address rank as you are still figuring it out. However, I
  would lean toward *not storing* it at all as it's a calculated value. If
  you store it it becomes a static value, and a maintenance issue. How
  often does updated.

**MISSING Elements:** Beside the indicated Add columns

- You have nothing to indicate a job offer sent to a photographer nor
  any method of capturing a negative response from them.
- You indicate scoring is dependent upon photographer's cancellation
  rate. But you have nothing to capture that. Perhaps the suggested
  Status in Requests but that's for you to decide.